# Solve differential equation $\frac{dT}{dz} = \beta(T(z) - T_{0})$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The supposed solution is $T(z) - T_{0} = C_{1}exp(-\beta z) + C_{2}$ but I don't know how to get to it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{dT}{dz} = \beta(T(z) - T_{0})$$

$$\int \frac{dT}{T(z)-T_0} = \int \beta \, dz$$

$$\log (T - T_0) = \beta z + \text{const.}$$

$$ T - T_0 = \exp(\beta z + \text{const.}) = C_1 \exp(\beta z).$$

Comment: Thank you, but how do we get the $C_{1}$ constant and the $-\beta z$ inside the exp?

Comment: Exponentiate both sides.  There is no $C_2.$  Also, the sign of $\beta$ is positive.

Comment: Okay, I see about the $C_{1}$. What about the minus?

Comment: $\int \beta \, dz = \beta z + \text{const.}$  Where did you get the answer?

Comment: From my teacher, it's actually an exercise about the temperature distribution of a fluid in a conduct that's used to evacuate heat. So we actually need it to be $exp(-\beta z)$ because when $z \longrightarrow \infty$ $T(z) = T_{0}$. I don't know, maybe a minus got lost somewhere on the way...

Comment: Well, maybe the right hand side is $\beta(T_0-T)$?

Comment: Or maybe $\beta < 0$?